# Ari Quiz no zero results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this code form Ari Quiz:

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE #__ariquizstatisticsinfo SET Status = %1$s,EndDate = %2$s,MaxScore = %3$f,UserScore = %4$f,UserScorePercent = %7$f, Passed = %5$d, ElapsedTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%2$s) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate) + UsedTime WHERE StatisticsInfoId = %6$d',
            $db->Quote(ARIQUIZ_USERQUIZ_STATUS_COMPLETE),
            $db->Quote($finishedDate),
            $finishedInfo['MaxScore'],
            $finishedInfo['UserScore'],
            $finishedInfo['Passed'],
            $statisticsInfoId,
            $finishedInfo['MaxScore'] > 0 ? min(round(100 * $finishedInfo['UserScore'] / $finishedInfo['MaxScore'], 2), 100.00) : 0.00

    );
```

but i need to not write in mysql database 0 results when no question is answered correct.
I modified with that:

```
    if ($finishedInfo['UserScore'] == 0.00) 
    {
    $resultes = 1.00;
    } 
    else
    {
    $resultes = $f;
    }
    $query = sprintf('UPDATE #__ariquizstatisticsinfo SET Status = %1$s,EndDate = %2$s,MaxScore = %3$f,UserScore = %4$resultes,UserScorePercent = %7$f, Passed = %5$d, ElapsedTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%2$s) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate) + UsedTime WHERE StatisticsInfoId = %6$d',
        $db->Quote(ARIQUIZ_USERQUIZ_STATUS_COMPLETE),
        $db->Quote($finishedDate),
        $finishedInfo['MaxScore'],
        $finishedInfo['UserScore'],
        $finishedInfo['Passed'],
        $statisticsInfoId,
        $finishedInfo['MaxScore'] > 0 ? min(round(100 * $finishedInfo['UserScore'] / $finishedInfo['MaxScore'], 2), 100.00) : 0.00
    );
```

but when i finish the test i got an error:

> 500 - AriQuizModelUserQuiz::markQuizAsFinished() : The following SQL
>   query can not be executed 'UPDATE #__ariquizstatisticsinfo SET Status
>   = 'Finished',EndDate = '2015-04-28 07:41:06',MaxScore = 2.700000,UserScore = esultes,UserScorePercent = 0.000000, Passed = 0, ElapsedTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-28 07:41:06') -
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate) + UsedTime WHERE StatisticsInfoId = 134'.
>   Details: Unknown column 'esultes' in 'field list' SQL=UPDATE
>   joomla_ariquizstatisticsinfo SET Status = 'Finished',EndDate =
>   '2015-04-28 07:41:06',MaxScore = 2.700000,UserScore =
>   esultes,UserScorePercent = 0.000000, Passed = 0, ElapsedTime =
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-04-28 07:41:06') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate) +
>   UsedTime WHERE StatisticsInfoId = 134

Thx in advance!

---

Back with updates:
I tried this code:

```
   $finaluserscore = '%4$f';
   if ($finaluserscore == 0.00)
   {
   $finaluserscore = 1.00;
   } else {
   $finaluserscore = '%4$f';
   }
   $query = sprintf('UPDATE #__ariquizstatisticsinfo SET Status = %1$s,EndDate = %2$s,MaxScore = %3$f,UserScore = ' . $finaluserscore . ',UserScorePercent = %7$f, Passed = %5$d, ElapsedTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%2$s) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate) + UsedTime WHERE StatisticsInfoId = %6$d',
   $db->Quote(ARIQUIZ_USERQUIZ_STATUS_COMPLETE),
   $db->Quote($finishedDate),
   $finishedInfo['MaxScore'],
   $finishedInfo['UserScore'],
   $finishedInfo['Passed'],
   $statisticsInfoId,
   $finishedInfo['MaxScore'] > 0 ? min(round(100 * $finishedInfo['UserScore'] / $finishedInfo['MaxScore'], 2), 100.00) : 0.00
    );
```

But i not undestand why if i got results 0.00 this put me 1.00 and if i got more than 0.00 all the same.

Comment: `Unknown column 'esultes' in 'field list' `.

Maybe you have a typo in that field's name?

Comment: Perhaps that should be %4$r

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a comma

```
UserScore = %4$resultes
```

could be

```
UserScore = %4$,resultes
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx all but i resolved myself, it's working now.

```
   $query = sprintf('UPDATE #__ariquizstatisticsinfo SET Status = %1$s,EndDate = %2$s,MaxScore = %3$f,UserScore = case when %4$f < 1.00 then 1.00 else %4$f end,UserScorePercent = %7$f, Passed = %5$d, ElapsedTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%2$s) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate) + UsedTime WHERE StatisticsInfoId = %6$d',
   $db->Quote(ARIQUIZ_USERQUIZ_STATUS_COMPLETE),
   $db->Quote($finishedDate),
   $finishedInfo['MaxScore'],
   $finishedInfo['UserScore'],
   $finishedInfo['Passed'],
   $statisticsInfoId,
   $finishedInfo['MaxScore'] > 0 ? min(round(100 * $finishedInfo['UserScore'] / $finishedInfo['MaxScore'], 2), 100.00) : 0.00
    );
```

If comment must be in sql not up in php:

UserScore = case when %4$f < 1.00 then 1.00 else %4$f end

Thx again to all!